# How multiple conditions inside if statement works

Tags: c

If multiple conditions are used in a single if statement then the testing of those conditions are done
a) from left to right 
b) from right to left
c) randomly
d) none

Comment: What happens when you try it out? You could  make several functions that return true/false and also print out their names and see what it shows you.

Comment: Could you possibly be less obvious about asking a homework question?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if-else conditions are evaluated **left to right**. The right condition will be evaluated only when the first condition is 'false' in case of 'or'.

```
if(false && condition) -> second condition doesn't get evaluated.
if(false || condition) -> second condition gets evaluated.
```

Similarly, The right condition will be evaluated only when the first condition is 'true' in case of 'and'.

```
if(true && condition) -> second condition gets evaluated.
if(true || condition) -> second condition doesn't get evaluated.
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I've been writing C professionally for 30 years and yet your answer left me a bit confused. You're not wrong but it's a poor explanation you need to work on.

Comment: @CareyGregory Are you sure it is correct? I don't understand it.

Comment: @Broman Yes, it's correct, but I'm not surprised you don't understand it. Go find another source to learn from.

Comment: @CareyGregory I mean. I can answer OP:s question without problem, but I cannot make any sense of this.

Comment: @Broman Then write your answer. Why do you need to understand someone else's answer? As you can see from my first comment, I find this answer confusing.

Comment: @Broman, This answer is trying to explain short circuiting but did not explain it well. As an example, in `if (false && condition)` the second part, `condition`, is not evaluated

Comment: @CareyGregory Done

Answer (score 2):

You cannot really have "multiple conditions" in an if statement. An if statement should have exactly one condition. This condition may be a combination of conditions, but in the eyes of the if statement, it is only one condition.

What this mean is that it is nothing special about how a condition inside an if statement is evaluated. It is evaluated the same way as if it were executed anywhere else.

This boils down to two different concepts: Operator associativity and Short circuiting.

**Associativity**

The logical operators have left to right associativity. That means that `cond1 && cond2` will evaluate `cond1` before it evaluates `cond2`.

**Short circuiting**

Short circuiting means that if `cond1` is false, then `cond2` will never be evaluated in the expression `cond1 && cond2`. Same goes if `cond1` is true in the expression `cond1 || cond2`

Comment: *This boils down to two different concepts* – add a third: Operator precedence.

Comment: *The logical operators have left to right associativity. That means that cond1 && cond2 will evaluate cond1 before it evaluates cond2* -- associativity has nothing to do with execution order. The ordering actually is a result of the short circuiting.

Comment: I'm also a little oncerned about many people only think about logical operators. Everything with an end result convertible to `bool` is fine.